# how to make the empty value for the day using moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs, lodash

I want to plot the data for the week in bar chart, how to give the empty value if the date is not there in the response object. I am using moment and lodash groupby for the find which day for the week.

```
const actionHistory = [
    {
      "c_code": "FIELD_VISIT",
      "amtp_actionTaken": "call",
      "amtp_takenOn": "2023-01-13T18:28:12.850Z"
    },
    {
      "c_code": "FIELD_VISIT",
      "amtp_actionTaken": "call",
      "amtp_takenOn": "2023-01-11T18:28:12.850Z"
    }
  ];
const weekdays = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
const month = groupBy(actionHistory, (dt) => moment(dt?.amtp_takenOn).days());
const result = map(month, (el, i) => ({ value: el?.length, label: weekdays[i - 1], frontColor: '#177AD5' });`
```

if i put console.log to result I getting the only the aviable date week days like this

```
[{"value":1,"label":"Tue","frontColor":"#177AD5"},{"value":1,"label":"Thu","frontColor":"#177AD5"}]
```

my expected output should be.

```
[{"value":0,"label":"Sun","frontColor":"#177AD5"}, 
 {"value":0,"label":"Mon","frontColor":"#177AD5"}, 
 {"value":1,"label":"Tue","frontColor":"#177AD5"}, 
 {"value":1,"label":"Wed","frontColor":"#177AD5"}, 
 {"value":1,"label":"Thu","frontColor":"#177AD5"}, 
 {"value":0,"label":"Fir","frontColor":"#177AD5"},
 {"value":0,"label":"Sat","frontColor":"#177AD5"}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. At least consult the [markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick

```js
const weekdays = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
let result = [{ "value": 1, "label": "Tue", "frontColor": "#177AD5" }, { "value": 1, "label": "Thu", "frontColor": "#177AD5" }];
result = weekdays.map((day, i) => {
  const res = result.findIndex(({ label }) => label === day);   // is label === day
  if (res !== -1) return result.splice(res, 1)[0];              // return the object
  return { "value": 0, "label": day, "frontColor": "#177AD5" }; // else return an object with value 0
})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for?

```js
const actionHistory = [
    {
      "c_code": "FIELD_VISIT",
      "amtp_actionTaken": "call",
      "amtp_takenOn": "2023-01-13T18:28:12.850Z"
    },
    {
      "c_code": "FIELD_VISIT",
      "amtp_actionTaken": "call",
      "amtp_takenOn": "2023-01-11T18:28:12.850Z"
    }
  ];
const [start,end]=actionHistory.map(el=>new Date(el.amtp_takenOn).getDay()).sort();
const res="Sun,Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat".split(",").map((wd,i)=>
  ({value:+(i>=start&&i<=end),label:wd,frontColor:'#177AD5'}));

console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

There are quite a few assumptions in my snippet:

- the datetime values in the objects of array `actionHistory`  are being interpreted as `start` and `end` dates. I sort them from smaller to larger weekday values (0 to 6 for Sunday to Saturday), so the starting weekday will have a smaller value than the ending weekday.
  `"2023-01-13T18:28:12.850Z"` is a Friday and `"2023-01-11T18:28:12.850Z"` is a Wednesday.
- all dates within the span defined by `start` and `end` will be given the value `1` and all others the value `0`.